# How to loop over directories in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a script in bash on Linux and need to go through all subdirectory names in a given directory. How can I loop through these directories (and skip regular files)?

**For example:**
the given directory is `/tmp/`
it has the following subdirectories: `/tmp/A, /tmp/B, /tmp/C`

I want to retrieve A, B, C.

Comment: This fits here: [How do I loop through only directories in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86722/how-do-i-loop-through-only-directories-in-bash)

Comment: **Solid array** under [tag:bash], (accepting spaced dirnames): `dirs=(/tmp/*/);dirs=("${dirs[@]%/}");dirs=("${dirs[@]#/tmp/}")`, then `printf "%s\n" "${dirs[@]}"` or `for dir in "${dirs[@]}" ;do ...`

Answer (score 147, accepted):

```
cd /tmp
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'
```

A short explanation:

- `find` finds files (quite obviously)
- `.` is the current directory, which after the `cd` is `/tmp` (IMHO this is more flexible than having `/tmp` directly in the `find` command. You have only one place, the `cd`, to change, if you want more actions to take place in this folder)
- `-maxdepth 1` and `-mindepth 1` make sure that `find` only looks in the current directory and doesn't include `.` itself in the result
- `-type d` looks only for directories
- `-printf '%f\n` prints only the found folder's name (plus a newline) for each hit.

Et voilà!

Comment: By the way: Note, that all answers will find hidden folders, too (that is, folders starting with a dot)! If you don't want this, add ` -regex '\./[^\.].*'` before the printf or exec options.

Comment: Helpful — if you need to execute only one command for each hit ;-) — Only I have several commands to execute :-( .

Comment: No problem: Adapt this solution: http://transnum.blogspot.de/2008/11/bashs-read-built-in-supports-0-as.html Inside the `while..done` loop you can go crazy.

Comment: This is a very nice method for some use cases; `find`'s `-exec` option lets  you run any command for each file/directory.

Answer (score 605):

All answers so far use `find`, so here's one with just the shell. No need for external tools in your case:

```sh
for dir in /tmp/*/     # list directories in the form "/tmp/dirname/"
do
    dir=${dir%*/}      # remove the trailing "/"
    echo "${dir##*/}"    # print everything after the final "/"
done
```

Comment: Well, yes, 'find' is kind of the Swiss Army knife on *NIX machines to find something file related. But a pure version with bash builtins only is good to know, too. +1

Comment: so `for dir in */; do echo $dir; done` is for directories in the current directory.

Comment: Would be nice if it could contain an explanation what `dir=${dir%*/}` and `echo ${dir##*/}` is doing.

Comment: `dir=${dir%*/} ` will strip the shortest match of `*/` from the end of dir, but what for?

Comment: It is because the variable dir will include the backslash at the end. He is just removing it to have a clean name. % will remove the / at the end. ## will remove the / at the beginning. These are operators to handle substrings.

Comment: If there's no match, the loop will be triggered with `/tmp/*/`, it would be wise to include a check to see if the directory actually exists.

Comment: @rubo77 It's hard to guess whether or not the author realizes that '%*/' is the same as the shorter and clearer '%/' in this context. The former, of course, makes you wonder what it is in front of the trailing slash that he's trying to remove, until you tediously work out that "shortest suffix" effectively means that any leading '*' in the pattern is ignored.

Comment: Perhaps using `echo \`basename $dir\`` would have been more clear for this answer.

Comment: What will happen if /tmp/ is empty !!

Comment: [`shopt -s nullglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) is handy here if you want zero iterations when `/tmp` does not exist.

Comment: Be careful: if there is no directory in the specified path, all files in the path will be listed, resulting in unwanted behavior. The solution with `find` is more reliable.

Comment: If there is no directory in a path, no only will the entire file list of that directory be iterated upon, you might have really bad performance if those directories have a large number of files.

Comment: If you want to exclude symlinks to directories, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86724/224565

Answer (score 65):

You can loop through all directories including hidden directrories (beginning with a dot) with:

```
for file in */ .*/ ; do echo "$file is a directory"; done
```

note: *using the list `*/ .*/` works in zsh only if there exist at least one hidden directory in the folder. In bash it will show also `.` and `..`*

---

Another possibility for bash to include hidden directories would be to use:

```
shopt -s dotglob;
for file in */ ; do echo "$file is a directory"; done
```

---

If you want to exclude symlinks:

```
for file in */ ; do 
  if [[ -d "$file" && ! -L "$file" ]]; then
    echo "$file is a directory"; 
  fi; 
done
```

---

To output only the trailing directory name (A,B,C as questioned) in each solution use this within the loops:

```
file="${file%/}"     # strip trailing slash
file="${file##*/}"   # strip path and leading slash
echo "$file is the directoryname without slashes"
```

#### Example (this also works with directories which contains spaces):

```
mkdir /tmp/A /tmp/B /tmp/C "/tmp/ dir with spaces"
for file in /tmp/*/ ; do file="${file%/}"; echo "${file##*/}"; done
```

Answer (score 23):

### Works with directories which contains spaces

Inspired by [Sorpigal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/235635)

```
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do 
    echo $file; ls $file ; 
done < <(find /path/to/dir/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0)
```

### Original post (Does not work with spaces)

Inspired by [Boldewyn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2107982/235635): Example of loop with `find` command.

```
for D in $(find /path/to/dir/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d) ; do
    echo $D ;
done
```

Answer (score 9):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%P\n"
```

Comment: That's nice too and eliminates the need for `basename`. I would prefer this over my answer.

Answer (score 7):

The technique I use most often is `find | xargs`.  For example, if you want to make every file in this directory and all of its subdirectories world-readable, you can do:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod go+r
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod go+rx
```

The `-print0` option terminates with a NULL character instead of a space.  The `-0` option splits its input the same way.  So this is the combination to use on files with spaces.

You can picture this chain of commands as taking every line output by `find` and sticking it on the end of a `chmod` command.

If the command you want to run as its argument in the middle instead of on the end, you have to be a bit creative.  For instance, I needed to change into every subdirectory and run the command `latemk -c`.  So I used (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#The_Shell_Trick)):

```
find . -type d -depth 1 -print0 | \
    xargs -0 sh -c 'for dir; do pushd "$dir" && latexmk -c && popd; done' fnord
```

This has the effect of `for dir $(subdirs); do stuff; done`, but is safe for directories with spaces in their names.  Also, the separate calls to `stuff` are made in the same shell, which is why in my command we have to return back to the current directory with `popd`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to execute multiple commands in a for loop, you can save the result of `find` with `mapfile` (bash >= 4) as a variable and go through the array with `${dirlist[@]}`. It also works with directories containing spaces.

The `find` command is based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2107982/7440933) by Boldewyn. Further information about the `find` command can be found there.

```bash
IFS=""
mapfile -t dirlist < <( find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' )
for dir in ${dirlist[@]}; do
    echo ">${dir}<"
    # more commands can go here ...
done
```

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR:

```sh
(cd /tmp; for d in */; do echo "${d%/}"; done)
```

### Explanation.

There's no need to use external programs. What you need is a shell globbing pattern. To avoid the need of removing `/tmp` afterward, I'm running it in a subshell, which may or not be suitable for your purposes.

#### Shell globbing patterns in a nutshell:

- `*` Match any non-empty string any number of times.
- `?` Match exactly one character.
- `[...]` Matches with a character from between the brackets. You can also specify ranges (`[a-z]`, `[A-F0-9]`, etc.) or classes (`[:digit:]`, `[:alpha:]`, etc.).
- `[^...]` Match one of the characters *not* between the braces.

** If no file names match the pattern, the shell will return the pattern unchanged. Any character or string that is not one of the above represents itself.*

---

Consequently, the pattern `*/` will match any file name that ends with a `/`. A trailing `/` in a file name unambiguously identifies a directory.

The last bit is removing the trailing slash, which is achieved with the variable substitution *`${var%PATTERN}`*, which removes the shortest matching pattern from the end of the string contained in *`var`*, and where *`PATTERN`* is any valid globbing pattern. So we write `${d%/}`, meaning we want to remove the trailing slash from the string represented by `d`.

Answer (score 3):

a minimal bash loop you can build off of (based off ghostdog74 answer)

```
for dir in directory/*                                                     
do                                                                                 
  echo ${dir}                                                                  
done
```

to zip a whole bunch of files by directory

```
for dir in directory/*
do
  zip -r ${dir##*/} ${dir}
done
```

Comment: This lists all files of `directory`, not only subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

`find . -type d -maxdepth 1`

Comment: this answer is good, except that i receive the full paths, while i want only the names of the directories.