# Loop over directories and act on files in bash script

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I have a script, /home/user/me/my_script.sh that is supposed to loop over multiple directories and process files. My current working directory is /home/user/me. A call to ls -R yields:

./projects:

dir1 dir2 dir3

./projects/dir1:

image1.ntf points2.csv image1.img image1.hdr

./projects/dir2:

image2.ntf points2.csv image2.img image2.hdr

./projects/dir3:

image3.ntf points3.csv image3.img image3.hdr

I have this script:

```
#! /bin/bash -f
for $dir in $1*
do
  echo $dir
  set cmd = `/home/tools/tool.sh -i $dir/*.ntf -flag1 -flag2 -flag3 opt3`
  $cmd
done
```

This is how it is run (from cwd /home/user/me) and the result:

```
bash-4.1$ ./myscript.sh projects/
projects/*
bash-4.1$
```

This is not the expected output.The expected output is:

```
bash-4.1$ ./myscript.sh projects/
projects/dir1
[output from tool.sh]
projects/dir2
[output from tool.sh]
projects/dir3
[output from tool.sh]
bash-4.1$
```

What should happen is the script should go into the first directory, find the *.ntf file and pass it to tool.sh. At that point I would start seeing output from that tool. I have run the tool on a single file:

```
bash-4.1$ /home/tools/tool.sh -i /home/user/me/projects/dir1/image1.ntf -flag1 -flag2 -flag3 opt3
[expected output from tool. lengthy.]
bash-4.1$
```

I have tried syntax found here: [How to loop over directories in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107945/how-to-loop-over-directories-in-linux) and here: [Looping over directories in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854559/looping-over-directories-in-bash)

```
for $dir in /$1*/
do ...
```

Result:

```
bash-4.1$ ./myscript.sh projects/
/projects/*/
```

And:

```
for $dir in $1/*
do ...
```

Result:

```
bash-4.1$ ./myscript.sh projects
projects/*
```

I'm not sure how many other iterations of wildcard and slash I can come up with. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Is the lengthy expected output from `tool.sh` a set of commands, or some other output?

Comment: It is text output about where the tool is in the process. It takes a *.ntf file and performs several calculations on the image to produce a calibrated image. A large image could take several minutes to process, so this output keeps the user informed about the progress.

Comment: So .. you appear to be trying to set the variable `$cmd` to the output of the script, and then running that output as if it were a command. What is your intent with that variable? Why not just run the tool directly? (Feel free to answer by clarifying in your question rather than comments.)

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ would catch at least a subset of the issues automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should remove flag `-f` in your shebang, because it utterly means:

```
$ man bash
[…]
        -f      Disable pathname expansion.
```

Second, there are some typical bug patterns: spaces missing around variables (write `"$dir"` to cope with directory names containing spaces), there is a spurious `$` in your `for` line (write `for dir in "$1"*`) instead, the `set` line is incorrect (`set` is a shell builtin only used to change the configuration of the shell, e.g., `set -x`), according to your answer to @ghoti's question it seems that the `$cmd` line is unnecessary. Also, the backquotes syntax is deprecated and could have been replaced with `cmd=$(/home/tools/tool.sh -i "$dir"/*.ntf -flag1 -flag2 -flag3 opt3)`.

This would lead to the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in "$1"*
do
  [[ -d "$dir" ]] || continue  # only consider existing folders
  printf "%s=%q\n" dir "$dir"
  /home/tools/tool.sh -i "$dir"/*.ntf -flag1 -flag2 -flag3 opt3
done
```

As an aside, I would recommend to always run the [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) static analyzer on your Bash scripts, in order to detect typical bugs and have feedback w.r.t. good practices. If you have a Linux distribution, it should be installable [with your standard package manager](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck#user-content-installing).

Comment: `"$1"*/`, if you want to only have directories as glob results. Otherwise files can show up too. Could alternatively use `[[ -d "$dir" ]] || continue` inside the loop -- that would also fix the case where no directories exist so you get a string with a literal `*` returned, without needing `nullglob`.

Comment: Indeed, @CharlesDuffy (thanks!) I've just added your second suggestion in my answer.

Comment: ...oh, might want to put a `\n` on the end of the `printf` format string. (Looks like something I may have written -- apologies if that thinko came from me!)

Comment: Thank you, this works! I will use ShellCheck extensively going forward. I am often building new scripts from other peoples scripts, so old practices get propagated forward when they should not.