# List only directories, including directories with spaces in their names?

Tags: bash

I would like to list all directories in a directory. Some of them have spaces in their names. There are also files in the target directory, which I would like to ignore.

Here is the output of `ls -lah data/`:

```
drwxr-xr-x    5 me  staff   160B 24 Sep 11:30 Wrecsam - Wrexham
-rw-r--r--    1 me  staff    77M 24 Sep 11:31 Wrexham.csv
drwxr-xr-x    5 me  staff   160B 24 Sep 11:32 Wychavon
-rw-r--r--    1 me  staff    84M 24 Sep 11:33 Wychavon.csv
```

I would like to iterate only over the "Wrecsam - Wrexham" and "Wychavon" directories.

This is what I've tried.

```
for d in "$(find data -maxdepth 1 -type d -print | sort -r)"; do
    echo $d
done
```

But this gives me output like this:

```
Wychavon
Wrecsam
-
Wrexham
```

I want output like this:

```
Wychavon
Wrecsam - Wrexham
```

What can I do?

Comment: @MatBailie No, it just doesn't descend into directories which are specified on the command line.

Comment: You misunderstand. `ls f d` lists `f` and the *contents* of `d` whereas `ls -d f d` simply lists `f` and `d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is not doing the right thing because of [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).  You can use a glob instead of having to invoke an external command in a subshell:

```
shopt -s nullglob # make glob expand to nothing if there are no matches
for dir in data/*/; do
  echo dir="$dir"
done
```

---

Related:

- [Looping over directories in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31307109/6862601)
- [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Thank you! This works, but (just to be annoying) I'd also like to list the directories in reverse order - is there a straightforward way to do that?

Comment: You could grab the directory names into an array with `dir_array=(data/*/)` and then sort the array following the steps mentioned in this post: [How to sort an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33359043/6862601).