# Loop over directories

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, sh

I'm not sure how to handle directories of directory scenario in shell.

I have folder structure as below.
Directory structure:

```
/DirA/DirA1/DirA11/*.txt  
/DirA2/DirA21/*.txt
/DirA3/DIrA31/*.txt'
```

I'm new to shell scripting, not able to figure out how to read these text files.

Comment: What do you mean by "read these text files" ? what do you want to do with them ?

Comment: It's better to ask a question when you have a problem than before trying.. As a tip, using two `find` should get you going: `find . -type d -iname DirA* -exec find {} -iname *.txt \;`. This command gives you all the `*.txt` files under a path that has `DirA*` in it.

Comment: @BarisDemiray You need to quote the patterns to prevent the shell from expanding them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm able to resolve it on looking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107945/how-to-loop-over-directories-in-linux

Answer (score 2):

You can use the find command to process all files with certain properties in a directory tree. For example,

```
find /DirA* -name '*.txt' 2>/dev/null
```

would list all files named *.txt inside the trees you are mentioning. Note that if you use wildcards in the name mask, you need to single-quote them in order to protect them from the shell.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm able to resolve it, on looking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107945/how-to-loop-over-directories-in-linux

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in /DirA/DirA1/DirA11/*.txt /DirA2/DirA21/*.txt /DirA3/DIrA31/*.txt; do
   # do stuff with $f
done
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm able to resolve it, on looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107945/how-to-loop-over-directories-in-linux