# Syntax error: operand expected (error token is “+”) (i coudn't resolve this problem with the other thread)

Tags: linux, shell

I cant get this simple program working the code looks like this because is for a class exercise I wouldn't do it like that but I have to, sorry if the code is a mess but I've tried so many things that the code is a bit "deformed"

```
n= 0
for x in /home
do
e= du $x -B1 | cut d" " -f 1
$sum$(($sum+$e))
done
echo $sum
```

Comment: So.. what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: to add the value one by one of the contents of /home to the value of sum and print it in the console

Comment: Add `echo $x` after the line with `do` and try to wonder what is the use of `for`? You can also add `echo $sum` to understand the error.

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: In the duplicate about looping over directories, see in particular the answer by ghostdog74 at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2108296/14122 (but don't copy their unquoted `echo` argument; that's bad form). Several of the bugs here can also be found in [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls); consider it recommended reading.

Answer (score 1):

At line 1 you have a space between the '=' and the 0, but there shouldn't be a spaces either before or after the '=' in an assignment.

At line 4 happens the same, but also you missed the backticks '`' around the commands, that indicate bash to evaluate what is inside the backticks and return the output of that command.

At line 5 it says:

```
$sum$(($sum+$e))
```

So did you mean:

```
sum=$(($sum+$e))
```

---

Update: I have found three problems more:

In line 2, replace `/home` with `/home/*`, because the former only uses /home in the loop, and the later returns every directory (and file) in the /home directory.

You are passing `d" "` to `cut`, the correct option is `-d " "`.

Also, `du` output is formatted with tabs, not spaces. If you delete the `-d " "` in `cut`, it works.

Comment: i've applied all the things you say, it does not work, same error. i dont know why it does not take the operation.

Comment: Please don't even mention backticks. The recommended form of command substitution is `$(...)`.

Comment: @mamg22 See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, particularly the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions" -- questions that don't focus on a single, narrow, specific bug should be closed, not answered.

Comment: Also, `-d" "` is perfectly valid. Even though the POSIX `cut` spec shows the option-argument separated on the `cut` page, see the last sentence of 2a in the [Utility Argument Syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01) specification noting that option-arguments do not strictly require that space.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.