# Mypy Cannot Find All Modules in Python3 Django App

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mypy

**Background**

I work in a large Python3 repo that is type checked with Mypy. In accordance with [PEP420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) we do not use `__init__.py` files.

Mypy recently added support for implicit namespace packages, but the implementation now follows the chain of `import` statements from a given entrypoint. In the case of this repo, (a Django app) there are many modules that are imported dynamically (like middleware) or not imported at all (tests and one-off scripts).

Consider this example:

```
my-py3-repo/
├── hello/
│   ├── services/
│   │   └── hello_service.py
│   └── hello.py
├── scripts/
│   ├── db/
│   │   └── migrate.py
│   └── manage.py
└── tests/
    └── hello/
        ├── services/
        │   └── hello_service_test.py
        └── hello_test.py
```

Assuming that `hello.py` imports `hello_service.py`, everything under the `hello` namespace will be type checked as expected with `mypy ./hello`.

**Problem**

However test discovery with `pytest`, `nose`, `django` et al works differently and `hello_test.py` would not usually import `hello_service_test.py`. There is currently no way for Mypy to discover `hello_service_test.py` with `mypy ./tests` (if not using `__init__.py`).

Similarly, everything under the `scripts` directory would suffer the same problem.

**Question**

How can I configure Mypy such that the `scripts` and `tests` directories are always type checked?

**Configuration**

```sh
# Pipfile
[dev-packages]
mypy = "==0.670"
[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

```sh
# setup.cfg
[mypy]
python_version = 3.7
ignore_missing_imports = True
namespace_packages = True
```

See also [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6385) I created in the Mypy repo.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be solved in Mypy alone, but here are some useful workarounds:

**1. Loop Over Files in Bash**

Simple version:

```sh
find . -iname '*.py' ! -name '__init__.py' | xargs mypy
```

But this fails if any two files have the same name (because Mypy attempts to import them both as top-level modules). Depending on your directory structure you can solve this by looping over separate applications/services that share module names:

```sh
for dir in ./myapp/*/;
    do find ${dir%*/} -iname '*.py' ! -name '__init__.py'\
    | xargs pipenv run mypy;
done
```

*adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2108296)*

...of course if you need this to exit with an error code, you have to wire it up yourself:

```
{
EXIT_STATUS=0
for dir in ./myapp/*/;
    do find ${dir%*/} -iname '*.py' ! -name '__init__.py'\
    | xargs pipenv run mypy;
    if [ $$? -eq 1 ]; then EXIT_STATUS=1; fi; \
done;
exit $EXIT_STATUS;
}
```

**2. Just Use Init Files**

Just give up and put `__init__.py` files next to any modules that Mypy can't find through the `import` chain.

I have submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6385) to the Mypy repo requesting a `--recursive` option (or similar) that would instruct Mypy to type check *all* `.py` files under a given directory and its subdirectories.

Hopefully this answer will be updated with a better solution when available.