Loop through subdirectories and use their names to edit the files within
I have a library of audio files organised as Audio/ArtistName/AlbumName/TrackName.ext. Much of the metadata is incorrect and I want to use FFmpeg Metadata to correct all the files at once.
I found this post to execute a command on files within subfolders. I still require, however, the name of subfolder ArtistName and the subfolder within AlbumName to execute the command on each audio file:
ffmpeg -i inputfile -metadata artist="Subfolder Artist Name" -metadata album="Subfolder Album Name" outputfile

How can I edit the metadata of the files based on the names of the subfolders they are in?
Edit: I am trying to do this in Linux CLI or Bash Script. I am trying to go through folders (artist) and then the subfolders within (albums) and loop through the files and run a command based on the names value of artist folder and album subfolder. I have tried this to loop through the folders but it does not work for the subfolders within to execute a command on the files in the subfolders. I was able to return the artist and album name but I still cannot get the track name. cd into the artist folder worked but not for the album folder
for artist in /tank/music/*/
do
    art= basename "${artist}"
    cd "${artist}"
    for album in ./*/
    do
        alb= basename "${album}"
        cd "${album}"
        for track in ./*/
        do
            echo "${art}"
            echo "${alb}"
            echo "${track}"
        done
    done
done


What programming language do you intend to use? Can you describe the changes you want to make in a way that does not require any deeper understanding of the music, but can be precisely described in simple terms? Have you tried anything?

Sorry it was not clear. I am trying to do this in Linux CLI or Bash Script. I am trying to go through folders (artist) and then the subfolders within (albums) and loop through the files and run a command based on the names value of artist folder and album subfolder. I have tried this to loop through the folders but it does not work for the subfolders within to execute a command on the files in the subfolders: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2108296/9954014

Don't add details to your question in comments. It gets buried there. Instead, [edit] your question to add it there, where it belongs, so that it is available to readers of the question.

As mentioned in  the [tag:bash] tag you have included, please learn to check your code at https://shellcheck.net before posting. Be sure to include #!/bin/bash (or similar) as the first line. If you still have problems, post the shellcheck corrected code with a note that you have used shellcheck. Good luck

If you cd down a level, you have to cd back out before you process another value at the same level.
I assume tracks are files and not directories.
Untested:
cd back out:
for artist in /tank/music/*/
do
    art=$(basename "${artist}")
    cd "${artist}"
    for album in ./*/
    do
        alb=$(basename "${album}")
        cd "${album}"
        for track in *.ext
        do
            trk=$(basename "$track" .ext)
            echo "${art}"
            echo "${alb}"
            echo "${trk}"
        done
        cd ..
    done
    cd ..
done

or use subshell so that cd out is implicit:
for artist in /tank/music/*/
do
    art=$(basename "${artist}")
    (
        cd "${artist}"
        for album in ./*/
        do
            alb=$(basename "${album}")
            (
                cd "${album}"
                for track in *.ext
                do
                    trk=$(basename "$track" .ext)
                    echo "${art}"
                    echo "${alb}"
                    echo "${trk}"
                done
            )
        done
    )
done

or just don't cd in the first place:
for artist in /tank/music/*/
do
    art=$(basename "${artist}")
    for album in "$artist"/*/
    do
        alb=$(basename "${album}")
        for track in "$album"/*.ext
        do
            trk=$(basename "$track" .ext)
            echo "${art}"
            echo "${alb}"
            echo "${trk}"
        done
    done
done


Alternative approaches:
# reduce typing
declare -n v=BASH_REMATCH

for f in /tank/music/*/*/*.ext; do
    if [[ -f $f ]] && [[ $f =~ .+/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)".ext"$ ]]; then
        echo "art=${v[1]} alb=${v[2]} trk=${v[3]}"
    fi
done

cd /tank/music
unset a
for f in */*/*.ext; do
    [[ -f $f ]] || continue
    IFS=/ a=(${f%".ext"})
    echo "art=${a[0]} alb=${a[1]} trk=${a[2]}"
done


"If you cd down a level, you have to cd back out".  I will argue that doing so is an unfortunately common anti-pattern.  Instead of changing directory and then changing back, it is much more robust to change directory in a subshell and then exit the subshell.

@jhnc, you overlooked pushd and popd.

@WilliamPursell yes, the post linked from the question (which I only just read) even shows an example of how things can go wrong

This worked perfectly. I tested it and it worked and it saved me so much time!
